# Search for ==, ++, etc

Tags: operators, search-engine

Google did not give me the results desired when querying for

```
python == and in or in
```

This is seemingly because google [omits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3737197/1587329) common programming language operators like `==` from search terms. Is there a way to get around this limitation?

[Previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132105/how-to-google-for-depend) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947612/how-do-i-search-google-for-code-and-other-programming-related-keywords-it-seems) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815683/how-do-you-search-the-web-for-programming-related-information?rq=1) google code search, yet that is shut down. Symbolhound.com was [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070052/1587329), yet returned an empty results page.

This is not about [searching for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778034/replacement-for-google-code-search), but instead searching for programming-related documentation (most often found on SO ;-), so are there any ways to search the web <sub>(or, for that matter, SO)</sub> for programming syntax?

Comment: Not that it answers your query well, but check out [stackse](http://stackse.com) as it searches stackoverflow for special characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's an answer on the [WebApps Stack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/10710/132396) I'll paraphrase here for posterity.

Write out the name of each symbol followed by "operator". Include the programming language if you want to be more specific.

```
Example                           Recommended Search
----------                        -----------
+= (addition assignment)          "plus equals operator"
%  (modulus)                      "percent operator"
^  (C++ bitwise XOR)              "caret operator C++"
```

Comment: Or search for "operator" and your language - you might find an overview page that lists your operator (and others)